# Tomcat 6 IP address restrictions

Tags: tomcat

I need to protect a certain folder within a web application of mine from access from outside of an defined IP range.

With [O'Reilly's Tomcat Tips](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html) I figured that:

```
<Context path="/path/to/secret_files" ...>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127.0.0.1" deny=""/>
</Context>
```

Is the way to go?

I'm not that much into tomcat configuration so I'm dazzled a little as to where to put these restrictions. Do I put this Within my web.xml or is this a thing I need to add to some general tomcat conf file?

Answer (score 2):

If we want to restrict ip adresses irrespective of the context path we should add the following line in server.xml( Engine name)

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1"/>
```

This will deny all the ip adresses except 127.0.0.1

If you want to aloow multiple ip's use the following

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1,10.10.12.13,10.132.12"/>
```

And if you want to deny from only one ip and allow all other ip's use the following

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" deny="127.0.0.1"/>
```

For multiple ip's

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" deny="127.0.0.1,10.10.12.13,10.132.12"/>
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include what changes need to be made, you only made reference to them.

Answer (score 1):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839618/tomcat-valve-settings) solved my problem.